# Trying to remove decimal from UISlider and text label

Tags: ios, uislider

I have a uislider connected to a label, when the slider moves, the label adjusts its value. I am able to set the increments and the max and min, but i can't figure out how to remove the decimal places from the value..i simply want whole steps. suggestions please

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(id)sender {

self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", (roundf(self.mySlider.value)];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display the result as an `int` instead of a `float`.

```
self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)roundf(self.mySlider.value)];
```

Comment: awesome, you rock! Thanks!